# preg_split regex on different characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I am trying to split up some titles into 3 parts:

```
Title: Name -- Edition
```

I'd like to split up these strings into

```
Array
(
    [0] => Title
    [1] => Name
    [2] => Edition
)
```

These titles may not have the edition, or the name field, or either of them.

Any help with this regex would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Thanks for everyones answers - I actually wrote this answer really quick as I had to step out the next minute. The "Title" "Name" and "Edition" can have other characters *possibly* I'm not entirely sure but it is possible. For example: **This is the Title?: The Specific Name 012 -- An individual Edition!!**

These characters (if they appear) will always be unique (**:** and **--**)

I will look over everyones answers in the morning, thank you for all your answers.

**EDIT #2**

To Clarify a little better, The title may or may not contain a name & edition, therefore these are also possible:

**This is the title! -- An Edition??** which should return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => This is the title!
    [1] => 
    [2] => An Edition??
)
```

Or

**This is the title!: A Name..** which should return

```
Array
(
    [0] => This is the title!
    [1] => A Name..
    [2] => 
)
```

Or just

**This is the title!** which should return

```
Array
(
    [0] => This is the title!
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)
```

Maybe regex is not the best solution for this? I don't know enough about regex unfortunately :(

Comment: I've posted an answer based on the string you provided, but looking at your question again, I'd like to clarify.. is it possible that the `title`, `name` and `edition` would have spaces or non-alpha characters? this would be pretty important as it affects the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work when Title, Name or Edition is not just one word:

```
preg_match("/([^:-]+(?=(?::|--|$))) (?::\s)? ([^(--)]*(?=(?:--|$))) (?:--\s)? (.*)/x", 'Long Title: With Long Name -- And an Edition', $output);
```

$output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Long Title: With Long Name -- And an Edition
    [1] => Long Title
    [2] => With Long Name
    [3] => And an Edition
)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Y7uE2IOelRTAz_fq)

Comment: This works as i'd expect, but not if I remove the Name or Edition. Is there a way to still return the results if those do not exist? Please see my update(s). Thanks for your answer

Comment: Updated the regex, try again.

Comment: Pretty close! The only thing that doesnt work is if I just have Long Title -- And an Edition (it just returns the full string)

Comment: Ok.. updated. Now it should be ok.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for all your help! Can you explain how it works a little bit? Regex is beyond my comprehension lol

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`preg_match_all()`](https://www.php.net/preg_match_all)

```
$str = 'Title: Name -- Edition';
preg_match_all('/\w+/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0])
```

Yields:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(5) "Title"
  [1] =>
  string(4) "Name"
  [2] =>
  string(7) "Edition"
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Darragh, I apologize about my vague question. Do my edits help with your question(s)?

Answer (score 0):

```
$subject = "Title: Name -- Edition";
preg_match("/(.+): (.+) -- (.+)/i", $subject, $matches);
```

Therefore

```
$matches[0] == "Title"
$matches[1] == "Name"
$matches[2] == "Edition"
```

Not tested